# Change a value in a dynamically generated drop down list

Tags: asp.net

Ok so I have drop down list connected to a datasource, and I need to change 2 or 3 of the values before they are displayed and I'm just having trouble figuring out what to do.  I'm assuming I setup some kind of loop to check the values, but thats all I can figure.  Does anybody have any general suggestions or resources they know that I can look up? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of object is the list in? A DataTable, List<>, a Linq to SQL query? Or something else?

Comment: don't know if this is what you mean but the sql datasource is querying a database for a list of categories, and I need to replace the underscored values with regular spaces eg. 'new_age' with 'New Age'

Comment: then why not do some string manipulation before you even get to the UI? Depends on what DAL you are using, but if you're using LINQ-SQL/LINQ-EF, you can easily modify the category values in a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your processing before you bind the datasource. So for example, create a dataset of results or arraylist, process the results changing your values and then bind to your dataset/arraylist.

You'll need to be more specific about what you are binding to and how you want to process for me to be more specific..

See link at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sd_patel/dropdownlistbox11222005064123am/dropdownlistbox.aspx